# How to load multi record text file into db

Tags: oracle, text, upload, etl

Trying to load this source text file into oracle db table, hitting a wall !

```
Year: 2019 Period: 03
Office: NY
Dept: Sales
Acct: 111222333
Status: Pending
1000|AAAAAAAAA|100,000.00
2000|BBBBBBBBB|200,000.00
3000|CCCCCCCCC|300,000.00
4000|DDDDDDDDD|400,000.00
......1000's more rows same format
```

ofcourse the table is of the following format

```
Year | Period | Office | Dept | Acct | Status | Line_no | Desc | Amt
```

I have the pipe delimited format load working, how do I handle the first 5 rows going into their corresponding columns and the rest of the file with line no's going into their corresponding columns. I have 100's of files with the same format.

Any direction / pointers appreciated.

Thanks,
CH.

Comment: rewrite the file with `awk` you have copy the "header" information into each sub-record? Good luck.

Comment: How are you loading it right now?  Are you using a tool like SQL Loader or external tables?

Comment: This is the first time we’re attempting to load this data. Given there are 100’s of files in the same format, I didn’t think External tables were an option. I was looking more at sqlldr. I’m open to other options as well.